# How to make GCC to warn for unintended assignment

Tags: gcc

When I added the compiler option `-Wparentheses` I get the warning

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

for this code

```
int x;

if (x = 0)
{
}
```

The condition in the `if` statement is erroneously an assignment instead of a comparison.

Now I want to pass the condition to a function using this macro:

```
#define check(condition,message) DoCheck(condition, message)
```

where the actual check for `condition!=0` is performed in the that function `DoCheck`. I would like to get the same warning for an erroneously assignment when I use this macro:

```
check(x = 0, "bla");
```

How can I tell GCC that the first parameter has to be treated similar to a condition of an `if` statement?

*Edit:* A change in the coding style would cause an error for unintentional assignment: `0 == x`. This would even not require any additional means. But I would like to catch the other errors too.

Comment: Many people inverts the values when doing comparisons, like e.g. `0 == x`. This will cause an error if you by mistake make an assignment instead.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: **#define check(condition,message) DoCheck(*(condition)?true:false*, message)** , gcc should recognize that *condition* should be a condition expression. Didn't try that out myself though.

Comment: Alright, it didn't work. but this would work: **#define check(condition,message) if(condition);DoCheck(condition, message)** be aware of that **;** right after if statement. This would give the gcc warning you want, but you'll be doing lots of useless cpu operation during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

A few general ideas (although not strictly applicable to your code and not tested):

I think if you declare the first parameter as bool (from stdbool.h) and activate conversion warnings, you should get a narrowing warning, because you go from int to bool and loose precision. At least it should do that, I'm not quite sure on that and would have to try that first in various conditions, as bool might be internally defined as int on older C standards, so if it's checked after the preprocessor it might not work, but it should be possible to get a warning on std=c11 or higher.

This of course would just not work for your example, because 0 and 1 are precisely the two values, but it would work for anything else if it would work at all.

The one thing other thing I can think of might be enums, as an enum parameter for a custom bool enum could be used to force casts. However, this would also make standard c boolean expressions necessary to cast, kind of defeating the point.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).